C++: Catching an exception thrown by a constructor of a parent class within a derived class
I have a base class, which throws an exception in the constructor. I call this constructor from the child constructor, but can't catch within the derived constructor the exception that is thrown from the parent constructor.
How is it possible to catch such an exception?
If not possible - what can I do, preferably without changing the parent class.
Here's the code:
    #include <iosteam>
    using namespace std;
    
    class Base
    {
    public:
        Base()
        {
            throw "Base throws an exception";
        }
    };
    
    class Derived : public Base
    {
        Derived() : Base()
        {
            // This will not be caught
            try
            {
            }
            catch (char *s)
            {
                throw "Derived throws an exception";
            }
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        try
        {
            Derived d();
        }
        catch (char *s)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << s << endl;
        }
    } 

Thanks

It seems that none of the answers in the duplicate mentions explicitly (but there are some highly upvoted comments about it) that even though you can use Function Try Block to catch this exception in the derived constructor, it will still be rethrown. So, you need try-catch block in your main anyway. Example. Also topic about function try block

@pptaszni it will be re-thrown only if no other throw happens, his case is 100% legit.
